# How to hide URL in address bar?

Tags: url, proxy, hide

I have made a website to display dataset for a publication that I am need to submit to a venue that needs blind review. My server is from the university so the link contains my college name and my name. How do I create a link that takes the viewver to my website without revealing my identity displayed by the URL?

My current URL looks like `univ.edu/myname/Dataset.html`. I do not want it to show `univ.edu` and `myname`. Anything else is ok.

Comment: Show a sample url and what you want it to look like.

Comment: what language do you use? If you send data through form then use POST rather than GET. Your send data won't be shown in url that way

Comment: I use html. My current url looks like https://univ.edu/myname/Dataset.html. I do not want it to show "univ.edu" and myname. Anything else is ok. If I create a short URL too it redirects me to same url. GET and POST hides data. This is server information.